# Bypass or establish a fixed OTP for a specific email auth0

Tags: django, react-native, auth0, review

We are preparing to submit our app for review on the Play Store and App Store. However, we’ve encountered a challenge related to our passwordless email OTP authentication. Specifically, we are seeking guidance on how to bypass or establish a fixed OTP for a specific email, which we can include with our app submission.

While transitioning to username-database authentication could address the issue, it’s important to note that this solution would be effective only for the initial release. Subsequent shifts from passwordless authentication back to username-database authentication in later releases might disrupt the existing user experience.

Could anyone please assist with this matter?